# Which is a good algorithm for solving this algorithmic puzzle?

Tags: c, dynamic, coin-change

I am given an amount say $50.
I am given some denominations say $1 ,$2 ,$5 etc. and the number of these denominations eg 1 ,5,6 that means 1 coin/note of $1 ,5 coins/notes of $2 and 6 coins/notes of $5.
I have to find the number of ways these coins can be used  to form this amount $50.
I am trying to think an efficient algorithm  to solve this in the fastest time possible.
Please note here the amount will never exceed $60.

Can someone please suggest which algorithm I can use to solve this problem?
Till now I have written a recursive solution for this problem but it is too slow for my purpose.I will be posting it here soon.

Comment: Sounds like you're either posting homework or challenges here... Should look at another place, like code golf ( http://codegolf.stackexchange.com ). If your recusrion is slow, think about "cached recursion" which would work well in your case (and keep in mind that you can sort to take highest bills first.

Comment: @RedX :Yes I know the knapsack problem but that is for lesser or equal weight/amount.

Comment: @Bruce:Well this is no homework/challenge.Search for this problem in any online active coding contest.If you find it .Delete this question immediately.Anyways I am still having summer vacations,so no question this being homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that this is not the place for homework, but still... The asker does not expect to get solution, he is only asking for a direction. let's not keep questions open unecessarily

Have a look at [Integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

Comment: Factorization isn't particularly helpful. Partitioning might be better.

Comment: Well this is no homework/challenge.Search for this problem in any online active coding contest.If you find it .Delete this question immediately.Anyways I am still having summer vacations,so no question this being homework

Comment: @friendzid: the above comment was for you

Comment: @AjaxAristodemos: ok. This might be adressed as a knapsack problem. This would work best with arbitrary coins (non-prime values). In your question you mentioned coins $1, $1 and $5, which are prime. By factoring original number you can easily tell (by comparing weighted-lists) if the answer is 0. Having two weighted-lists for coins and factors you only need to count combinations - simple math